# Calendar event list shows deleted events. How can i hide them?

Tags: php, zend-framework, list, events, hidden

On my homepage i am displaying a list of events created in my google calendar. 
see: [my homepage-> eventlist](http://www.takenosono.de/termine.phtml)

now i have deleted events from my calendar. These are no longer visible in the regular Google calendar, but now they have appeared in my event list.

This is the script for my event list:

```
<a href="http://www.takenosono.de/termine.phtml">
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');

$service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar();

$query = $service->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser('mymagiccookie%40group.calendar.google.com');
$query->setVisibility('public');
$query->setProjection('full');
$query->setStartMin(date('Y-n-j'));
$query->setStartMax(date('Y-n-j', time() + (60*60 *24*60)));
$query->setOrderby ('starttime');
$query->setSortOrder('a');
//$query->setFutureevents(true);
$eventFeed = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
echo "<h3>Besondere Termine:</h3><h6>";
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'deu', 'de_DE.UTF-8');

foreach ($eventFeed as $event) {
echo "" . $event->title->text .   "\n";
// Zend_Gdata_App_Extensions_Title->__toString() is defined, so the
// following will also work on PHP >= 5.2.0
//echo "\t<li>" . $event->title .  " (" . $event->id . ")\n";

foreach ($event->when as $when) {

$startTime = $when->startTime;
$endTime = $when->endTime;

echo "<br>" . strftime("%a %d. ", strtotime( $startTime )); 
if (strftime("%d.", strtotime( $endTime )) != strftime("%d.", strtotime( $startTime ))):
echo strftime("bis  %d. ", strtotime( $endTime ));
endif;

echo strftime("%b", strtotime( $endTime ));

if (strftime("%d.", strtotime( $endTime )) == strftime("%d.", strtotime( $startTime ))):
echo strftime(" - %H:%M", strtotime( $startTime ));
endif;
echo "<br><br><img src='picture/Trenner.gif'><br>";
 }

 }
 echo "mehr: hier klicken...";
 ?>
</a>
```

The question is: What can i do so that deleted events are no longer displayed in this list?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just use event status like this:

```
foreach ($eventFeed as $event) {
    if ($event->getEventStatus() != 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.canceled')
    {
        //your foreach code
    }
}
```